# Getting error '(400) bad request: The specified block list is invalid.' when uploading text to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: .net, azure-blob-storage

I implemented the following code to upload text to an Azure block blob:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = ... 
CloudBlobClient blobClient = ...
CloudBlobContainer container = container.CreateIfNotExists();
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob");
blockBlob.UploadText(blob);
```

Periodically I get the following exception from the UploadText() operation:

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()...
>   RequestID:27e93ddb-0001-0011-2113-0966db002000 RequestDate:Sat, 17 Oct
>   2015 19:38:47 GMT StatusMessage:The specified block list is invalid.
>   ErrorCode:InvalidBlockList

I understand the importance of sending a properly ordered list of block IDs and having consistent block ID lengths when uploading a blob but given that UploadText hides these details I would not assume that a block list issue could occur unless there was a bug in the framework.  Obviously under the covers UploadText() is calling the REST API and dealing with blocks, but again, that's all hidden.

The text I am uploading is between 1kB and perhaps 15MB and is UTF-8 encoded.